# Do lands outside Westeros play a role just insofar as they affect Westeros?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Is there any indication that the resolution to the story would include significant developments in cities like Bravos or the other Free Cities or any other lands beside Westeros and Slaver's Bay.

As a reader first and foremost we need to know how Westeros will be resolved.  Secondarily we're curious about whether Daenerys will have to abandon Slaver' Bay and how it will turn out for Slaver's Bay.  But what about the Free Cities and majority of the Dothraki not under Daenerys and those other lands mentioned?  Remember only Westeros is threatened by "Others".  Is there any indication that GRRM has any plans for these other lands, or are they supposed to just remain as they are while Westeros proceeds thru these epic historical events?

Comment: Dothraki have their prophecy of "the stallion who mounts the world", which would have been Dany's child Rhaego, or Drogon, assuming Dany's impromptu blood magic worked.

Answer (score 5):

I think the satisfactory ending is supposed to be the prevention of cold white dead things pouring south and extinguishing all human life, and the rest of it is secondary.  For GRRM, *something less than everybody dying* qualifies as a happy ending.

Comment: Well remember only Westeros is threatened by Others and Wights.  Others are not seafaring.

Comment: @JoeC When hell freezes over, oceans will probably do the same. ;)